# Deep link with variable query on branch.io

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

We are considering using branch.io for the social sharing aspect of our app.  I'm also wondering whether I can use it for the password reset flow. This is to get around the fact that email clients like gmail strip the custom application uri like:

```
frock//:foo.com/reset-pw
```

out of any links: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme/issues/123.

So I'm thinking about using branch.io to send out a link to the password recover screen and am wondering if I have to create a branch.io link for each user, or whether I can create one link call it /reset-pw and then pass it a variable query parameter like so:

```
 /reset-pw?token=foo
```

Or does each url plus query combination require that I register a link with branch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Full disclosure, currently employed at Branch.

You can certainly create a single link and append query parameters like you have in your example, but you'll need to integrate the Branch SDK & make sure you've set up an account. More info on creating those types of links [here](https://dev.branch.io/link_creation_guide/#appending-query-parameters).

Branch uses a reserved keyword called "$deeplink_path" that allows you to specify the portion that comes after "frock://". Simply do the following:

https://bnc.lt/a/key_live_xxxx?$deeplink_path=%2Freset-pw%3Ftoken%3Dabc

and Branch will pass through that token key value pair. (again, assuming you've set the SDK up and registered for an account).

Comment: I am finding that the values are coming back all lowercase (despite what I enter), is that expected?

Comment: When I click this link it always wants to go to the app store even after I've sideloaded the app for debugging.