# Branch.io - Appending Query Parameters

Tags: url-parameters, branch.io

Trying to append some query parameters to links created via Branch.io, but I can't figure out how to do this in the dashboard. I see from https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/ that the following is possible.

1. Short links can have additional data appended to them
   e.g. dynamic link https://example.app.link/fzmLEhobLD?content_id=123
2. Append query strings https://example.app.link/fzmLEhobLD?$custom_data=123&hello=world

Is there a way to do this via Quick Links in the dashboard?

I need to create the link here to test that my Android and iOS apps can read the parameters from the link and take the user to the appropriate page, or redirect the user to the appropriate page on the website - and then bulk create similar links with the query parameters varying (either via the dashboard or the HTTP API).

Have already checked out the following - [Deep link with variable query on branch.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448437/deep-link-with-variable-query-on-branch-io) - but this didn't seem to address the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a quick link under configure options, you can select the deep linking tab and click on the "+ more data" button which will allow you to add parameters to the quick link.

[adding parameters to quick link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Kb7.png)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add query params in the dashboard, but you can add link data in the Link Data section. (date of the screenshot: Jan, 2021)
[image: branch.io query params link data key value properties]
If you need links for different purposes, then you should create multiple links.

On the other hand, if you only need to vary one parameter, then you can reuse one link by passing a different query parameter. For example, you can create a Quick Link to add a user to a user group that looks like this - `myapp.link/add`, That is a Quick Link, and you can set its params in the Link Data section (e.g. set key `type` to value `new_users`

Then, on the backend (or wherever you want to "generate" links), you reuse that one link like this:

```
myapp.link/add?code=a1      this is inviting user L to group Y
myapp.link/add?code=b2      this is inviting user M to group Z
```

In your app, you can access both the `code` param (from query param) and the `type` param (defined in Link Data) in the same way, usually through a data Map.